# ASP.NET MVC - Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an asp.net application that I mainly develop on a windows machine and everything runs fine with no errors. However, when I try and run this on my Mac after I pulled it from git I keep getting an error when trying to update database:

```
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.
```

I don't have a sql server for my Mac yet but if I try and update-database I should get an error something like:

```
database doesn't exist
```

Yet its the applicationDbContext that fails.
this is my ApplicationDbContext:

```
namespace ProjectFlow.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Workspace>Workspaces { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TaskStatus> TaskStatuses { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

And my Program.cs

```
ar connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultUI().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

As I stated above this works perfectly on my windows but not on my Mac if anyone knows the reason why.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can share your connection string sample. I hope you are using LocalDB for windows. unfortunately LocalDB is not available for Visual Studio for Mac. Just have a look!.